# Why does the statement after the comment Digit 2 is getting marked as "unreachable"?

Tags: java

In the following code, the statement after ''Digit 2 is marked as unreachable. Why?

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("Welcome to Pi Conquest!");
    System.out.println("Name as many digits of Pi as you can");
    System.out.println("If you get an error you restart");
    System.out.println("Only includes up to 100 digits of Pi");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Digit 1
    System.out.println("Stats:");
    System.out.println("Number of Digits Entered: 0");
    System.out.println("Digits Entered: 3.");
    System.out.println("Enter the first digit of Pi. (Starting with decimals)");

    int digit1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(digit1==1){
        System.out.println("Correct, enter the next digit.");
        continue;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect, restarting.");
        break;
    }

    //Digit 2     <--------------------------------------- next statement marked unreachable
    System.out.println("Stats:");
    System.out.println("Number of Digits Entered: 1");
    System.out.println("Digits Entered: 3.1");

    int digit2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(digit2==4){
        System.out.println("Correct, enter the next digit.");
        continue;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect, restarting.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in the previous `if`, either the branch that ends with `continue` or the branch that ends with `break` will be executed.

Both these instructions will cause the current iteration to end, so there is no way in which more code may be executed.

Comment: How could I fix it then?

Comment: you don't need 'continue'. @^^

Comment: Remove the continue in if, and change break into a continue.

Comment: From the text in your `system.out.println`, I would say that you should delete the `continue`. Anyway, it is just a guess. Since it is you who know what the program should do, my advice is to read what `continue` and `break` do and decide if they are appropiate for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The first option in this statement leads to restarting the loop, and the second one - ends the loop and starts execution of code after the while loop. So, the next lines won't be reached.

```
if(digit1==1){
        System.out.println("Correct, enter the next digit.");
        continue;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect, restarting.");
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `continue` and `break` wrong. Your `break`s should be `continue`s and your `continue`s should be simply removed.

```
if(digit1==1){
    System.out.println("Correct, enter the next digit.");
}else{
    System.out.println("Incorrect, restarting.");
    continue;
}
```

`break` exits the `while(true)` loop and since there's nothing else after that loop, your program ends. Instead, you want to start a new loop iteration at this point (and skip over the remaining of the current iteration), thus you need a `continue`.

As mentioned earlier, `continue` starts a new loop iteration. Instead, you want to simply go on with the current iteration. You don't need anything fancy for this: just let the `if` block do its thing and continue after the `if...else` statement.

Off-topic: you'll have quite a lot of code duplication if you continue in this fashion for the other digits. I suggest you look into making a `for` loop *over the digits of pi* so you can compare the "current digit" with the entered number.

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement either fails or continues the loop (it does not continue the "code"), so nothing after the first if statement will ever be executed.

You might want to consider coding your request differently (e.g. step through the digits of pi in a String answer, providing feedback to the user.

Answer (score 0):

All code below `//Digit 2` comment is unreachable. I think that you didn't get what `continue` statement means. When you run `while` loop it gets int from keyboard by

```
int digit1 = keyboard.nextInt();
```

and according to your code

```
if(digit1==1){
    System.out.println("Correct, enter the next digit.");
    continue;
}else{
    System.out.println("Incorrect, restarting.");
    break;
}
```

If it is `1` it will start loop from begining. Otherwise loop will break. I think that you expected `continue` to run your code after `if else` statement but `continue` runs loop again from the very begining.
If you want to run next line of code after `if else` just remove continue.